# SFML 2.1 - Detecting a single mouse click and changing a texture

Tags: c++, textures, sfml

What I'm trying to do is:
I have a sprite. And this sprite has 3 textures. First texture, let's call it "not-visited", is the initial one. Now, when I click on the sprite it should change it texture to "clicked" meaning that the sprite was clicked. And this texture should remain until I click somewhere else on the screen. When I do this, the texture should change to the third one, "visited". And if I click on the sprite again it should change its texture to "clicked"...

So, I should have here a bool function called "ClickDetected" and its code should do this:

```
if (event.type == Event::MouseButtonReleased && event.mouseButton.button == Left)
   if (mouse_over_sprite)
      return true;
```

Right? OK, then, I have a class Node. This class has a method "Clicked":

```
bool Clicked {
   if (ClickDetected) { return true; }
}
```

I know it may be unnecessary, but let it stay for now. Next, in Update() method of this class:

```
if (Clicked) { change_texture_to_"clicked"; if (!visited) visited=true; }
else {
   if (!visited) change_texture_to_"not-visited";
   if (visited) change_texture_to_"visited";
}
```

But this doesn't work how it should. When I click on sprite texture changes to "clicked". When I release the mouse button the "clicked" texture stays... But when I move the mouse texture changes to "visited". And it should remain "clicked", until I click somewhere else. I tried to use a while loop here, but it didn't work. What can I do?

Comment: It's hard to find coding errors when you post pseudo code. Can you post your real code?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but I've already found the error and fixed it :)

Comment: Would you mind writing a short answer and accept it, so this question gets marked as resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I've put this code to Graph class (method Update()) to manage many Nodes. I've change it a little bit and now it works fine.